# EOS CDT: where are the *.h and the *.cpp files stored in the filesystem, I need reference to them to compile

Tags: c++, ubuntu, smartcontracts, eos

I'm trying to use the EOS CDT (contract development toolkit).

I've downloaded and installed the repository from github, and used to following commands, as indicated from the eos.io development page.

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/installing-the-contract-development-toolkit

console commands:

*wget https://github.com/eosio/eosio.cdt/releases/download/v1.3.2/eosio.cdt-1.3.2.x86_64.deb*

*sudo apt install ./eosio.cdt-1.3.2.x86_64.deb*

I can't find the reference to the h and cpp files in ubuntut's (16.04.5) filesystem.
Where are they?

I need to reference them for compiling the test codes and the examples.
I'm also using visual studio code ide.

Comment: Have you looked at the paths that are indicated by the link you sent  /usr/local/include/eosiolib/ Was apt install successful?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Yes, the install was successful, I did not see any error message. I've looked in the /usr/local/include/ path but "eosiolib" is missing

Comment: Well, that's the location said they should be, so you should ask EOS directly!

Comment: Unless the debian file is really special, you can see which files it contains (and thus installs to your filesystem) with `dpkg -c eosio.cdt-1.3.2.x86_64.deb`

Comment: @Botje thanks, the CDT files are stored in /usr/opt/eosio.cdt/

Answer (score 1):

Based on Botje's comment:

*"Unless the debian file is really special, you can see which files it contains (and thus installs to your filesystem) with dpkg -c eosio.cdt-1.3.2.x86_64.deb"*

using the command:

dpkg -c eosio.cdt-1.3.2.x86_64.deb

The folder where the files are installed are shown:

The CDT files are stored in **/usr/opt/eosio.cdt/**

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS users reference, when installing with Brew include paths are located at

```
/usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.4.1/opt/eosio.cdt/include/
```

(Please use your own version instead of 1.4.1 if applicable)